# Using tracking detector in a double slit experiment, what would we see?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, particle-detectors

Let's say we put tracking detector (eg. a cloud chamber or a more advanced device) behind the double slits.

What would we see?

I think the interference pattern is three dimensional. So there are hyperbolic regions where waves cancel. So in these regions we wouldn't see particles. But speaking of a tracking detector, which direction the streaks would point to then?

Searching in the topic on the other hand I found a different view that says that the detector would reveal via the trajectory which slit the particle come from, so no interference pattern at all. But this way how would particles know in advance what kind of device I want to measure them?

Comment: A later, similar question got much more attention: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193364/has-a-double-slit-experiment-ever-been-done-using-a-track-chamber-or-even-contem.

Answer (score -1):

That's an excellent suggestion for an experiment since Claus Jönsson has performed his experiment with electrons at a double slit. Since the electrons must be in a vacuum, it is questionable whether the diffraction pattern shows in a cloud chamber.

However, if it succeeds it may be, that in a single-photon experiment one can see the gap through which electron passes. If so, the interpretation of the summary diffraction pattern by interfering with itself single electrons must be reconsidered. Then it will be legitimate to consider the influence of the ever-present electromagnetic field of the double slit on the electron. The EM field is always present because of the outer or free electrons in every material. And this EM field is quantized according to todays physics.