# Is it possible to plot a quantum particle's position with respect to time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem

If I shoot an electron through a substance, is it theoretically possible to plot its path through said substance?

Has this been experimentally done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to watch it then you just find out how watched electrons move. Or as dmckee reminds us, the quantum zeno effect might even stop them from having a chance to move.

If you don't watch it then you don't see it so you don't know how they moved or whether they even just appear where you see them.

You can try so called weak measurements to try a bit of both, but it's not really what you want, but I could be wrong. Study weak measurements if you think it's good to study, maybe it is what you want.

Another option is to make a detailed theory about the probability of it being different places. Done. And then make a detailed theory about the probability flow. Done. And then when you do a measurement of position at one time you can mathematically compute the streamline that ended there and retrodict that it followed that streamline.

The biggest problems are firstly that it is pointless (retrodictions make no predictions) so not much effort it devoted to it and secondly that the probability is based on entire configurations of every particle and we don't observe all the particles. Therefore, if you only measure one or two particles or so then there are still lots of streamlines through the space of all configurations.

Comment: But, if you did do all of this "pointless" stuff. Would it be a realistic path followed if there was no observation?

Comment: @Zach466920 It would be a mathematical plot about what happens when you don't look. By definition you would never know if you are right. It would be entirely possible, believable, and consistent.

Comment: Ok, but if you did this by experiment, you would *not* get something consistent with the predictions of the mathematical model? I'd assume you'd have to have multiple trials, electron shootings, to realize this.

Comment: @Zach466920 When you do it experimentally you get a position at a time. And you can place detectors at different locations for different runs and you can measure fluxes too at each place but you can't know that the one you see was doing what you think before you looked. But it isn't unreasonable.

Comment: But, you couldn't measure all the positions at all the times in a single trial? I imagine being able to have a "light trail" representing where the electron went. Could you obtain this "light trail"?

Comment: @Zach466920 The way you measure something requires you interact with it, and change it into something else. So measuring it again wouldn't tell you about what it used to be. We shouldn't use the word measure.

Comment: Ok, so you can plot the path it takes, but it's not representative of the path the electron takes if the path was not plotted. In this case plotting requires measurement.

Comment: @Zach466920 I still worry you are missing the point. The mathematical streamline is a streamline in configuration space. And so to know the streamline you need the entire configuration. Otherwise there are still many streamlines to retrodict. Ones that could have very different paths for your electron. And yes these streamlines are about what happened when you didn't look so if you look you just get a single snapshot. And if you run it again you get a different final configuration so a different retrodicted streamline.

Comment: So this can't be done in practice because we don't and can't know the configuration of the system?

Comment: @Zach466920 If it is a small enough system it might be doable, I've seen people do it for the double slit (For instance "Bohmian Trajectories in the Double-Slit Experiment" http://youtu.be/CAwEPLWe7jM ). And I've seen chemists do it for chemical kinetics for quantum chemistry. The MIW (not MWI, it is something different) was originally based on numerically replacing the Schrödinger equation with computations of streamlines instead.

Comment: Ok thanks, final question. I looked around a bit and found this [question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193364/has-a-double-slit-experiment-ever-been-done-using-a-track-chamber-or-even-contem). It talks about these chambers that plot the position. Could this be done if we ignored technological difficulties?

Comment: @Zach466920 If you watch the 20 second video I linked or just look at a picture of some streamlines you've that a degree of interference occurs at every place you could put the screen when you have a cloud chamber you basically follow the streamline as the cloud parts move around until you get close to one them. Then since the streamline is in configuration space (hopefully you know what that is because it is essential) then you diverge in the configuration in the part saying where the cloud part is. This means the streamline is guided by waves that don't interfere. If you watch the animation

Comment: @Zach466920 You'll see the wave and the streamlines. The wave guides the streamlines in dBB (but its all streamlines in MIW and all wave in MWI) so when the wave no longer has interference you don't get those fast movements near the troughs or the slow downs near the peaks you get boring classical like trajectories. The experiment you describe seems utter boring and un illuminating and entirely predictable and even unnovel.

Comment: I watched the video, and I kind of get what your saying. Since the configuration space consists of trajectories, determining which one you have makes this space disintegrate? I think I'll form a question about theoretical limitations on the linked experiment. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: In the context of *"If you try to watch it then you just find out how watched electrons move."* it might be useful to mention the [quantum Zeno effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Zeno_effect).